# How could I link a linux .so shared library in Mac os?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I have third party who gives to me `.so` file which is already compiled shared library.

Just Like:

```
file securitymduserapi.so 
securitymduserapi.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

but when I try to use `otool` to show more info, I got this error:

```
otool -L securitymduserapi.so 
securitymduserapi.so: is not an object file
```

It's that possible to link linux compile .so shared library in macos.

Mac os version: 10.10.3

I'm still wondering about the linux architecture with the mac, If I create a shared library in linux, Can I try to use this shared library in mac os?

Comment: You usually cannot link a Linux shared object on MacSX. The ABIs are different. Did you consider running Linux inside some VM ?

Comment: You need to request a Mac version of the library, or run on Linux (usually the specific version that the .so was compiled with, or as close as possible).  @EmployedRussian has your answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> If I create a shared library in linux, Can I try to use this shared library in mac os?

You can *try*, but you can't succeed.

You wouldn't expect to be able to use Windows `.DLL` on MacOS, would you? A Linux `.so` is no different in this context.